# how can I shrink all children <img> inside a div responsively without them breaking row

Tags: html, css

I have the following html:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <img src="1">
    <img src="2">
    <img src="3">
    <img src="4">
</div>
```

`.wrapper` has `!important` as for special media queries of show/hide, disregard unless cardinal:

```
max-width: 100%;
margin: auto!important;
display: block!important;
float: none!important;
padding: 0 80px;
```

All `img` have:

```
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
```

## so with these 3 share button images:

[image]

## I would like them to shrink responsively and not break like this:

[image]

## If I narrow the width more, the only shrinking image is facebook because of it's unique width.

[image]

So how do I solve this?
Please provide simple CSS/HTML rules that adhere to browser compatibility as much as possible and no JS.

thanks and I hope you like red arrows like I do,
Bud

Comment: take google+ and twitter into another wrapper. So that when it breaks it will break by google + icon.

Comment: Can you please provide working example of the problem?

Comment: In this case it might make more sense to have the `width` be auto, and adapt the `height` ...

Comment: Just use `flexbox` 

.wrapper {display: flex;}

Comment: @CBroe - any working example?

Comment: Try adding a `white-space: nowrap` to .wrapper, it should stop the images wrapping to a new line.

Comment: _“any working example?”_ - funny you should ask, please create a [mcve] for us to play with first.

Comment: @SuperUser this is the result of display: flex; on parent: http://prntscr.com/h4r45n

Comment: All you have to change is your img width to 20%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to have fun with stuff like this. If we give things some Ids and classes, then we can set a width percentage on them and then they can maintain the ratio by themselves

```
<div id="social_icon_wrapper" class="wrapper">
  <img class="img_facebook" src="1">
  <img class="img_google"   src="2">
  <img class="img_twitter"  src="3">
</div>
```

So, if we work out the maximum size that we want everything to be, we can do some maths and work out their percentages

```
social_icon_wrapper = 213
img_facebook = 120, 120/213 = 0.56
img_google = 42      42/213 = 0.20
img_twitter = 42     42/213 = 0.20
gap = 3               3/213 = 0.014
```

Then the CSS would look like this

```
#social_icon_wrapper 
{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}

#social_icon_wrapper img
{
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 1.4%;
    width: 20%;
}

#social_icon_wrapper img.img_facebook
{
    width: 56%;
}
```

Comment: I really like how you set it, but I think something in the calculations is off a bit.
result:http://prntscr.com/h4rjdu

Comment: I found it, its perfect, the margin-right wasn't added into the calc. thanks buddy. just fix that and i'll put your answer up.
I love it that all those commentators didn't understand that someone who knows his stuff in HTML/CSS doesn't need to `play with it` :) :) thanks again.

Comment: Yes! Good spot. Got a bit carried away there. I'll edit the answer